# How to have a Indicator on the GNOME Top Bar that displays the output of a command for every x seconds

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, top-bar

How to have a Indicator on the GNOME Top Bar that displays the output of a command for every x seconds.

Comment: Your app when opened or always??

Comment: Always. Thanks @UnKNOWn

Comment: Just to see if it run or not. In fact, I want to be able to find out if my ssh-tunnel is running or was close.

Comment: `ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
desktop-icons@csoriano`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126691/discussion-between-zvi-and-unknown).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This extension can make what you are looking for https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2932/executor/

https://github.com/raujonas/executor

[image]